# Sharepoint Library/List into HTML site(using Page Viewer)

Tags: jquery, html

I am having an awful hard time with understand the SPService and JQuery files and how to use them to get what I want done.

I am looking to take a list/library on my SharePoint site and input the data into html coding that I am hosting on the same SharePoint site (through the page viewer option).  I am doing this to get a more web based look, but to make updating and adding items easier by keeping the SharePoint lists/libraries.

Can someone help me as to where to start?

This works to pull into a cewp, but I need it to be able to work within the HTML coding of the page viewer webpart.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        webURL: "http://myURL.aspx",
        async: false,
        listName: "Announcements",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
          $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
            var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
            $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
          });
        }
      });
    });
</script>
<ul id="tasksUL"/>  
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need page viewer webpart.?

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: If you're doing this simply to maintain the look, I recommend you look at branding and style options rather than using a page viewer. I also recommend using newer SPServices and JQuery versions. Yours are quite old.

Answer (score 1):

**You can get anonymous list items in a HTML page using below code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN” “http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd”&gt;
 <html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”&gt;
 <head>
 <title></title>
 <script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js”></script&gt;

<style type=”text/css”>
table.hovertable {
 font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:11px;
 color:black;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: black;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;

}
 table.hovertable th {
 background-color:#D3E2E5;
 border-width: 1px;
 padding: 8px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 }
 table.hovertable tr {
 background-color:white;
 }
 table.hovertable td {
 border-width: 1px;
 padding: 8px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 color:#666666;
 }
 </style>

</head>
 <body>
 <div>

<script type=”text/javascript”>

$(document).ready(function () {

$(“#tblCalendar > tbody:last”).children().remove();

var soapEnv =
“<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=’http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/’&gt; \
 <soapenv:Body> \
 <GetListItems xmlns=’http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/’&gt; \
 <listName>AnonymousList</listName> \
 <query> \
 <Query> \
 <Where> \
 <Eq> \
 <FieldRef Name=’DateValue’ /> \
 <Value Type=’DateTime’><Today/></Value> \
 </Eq> \
 </Where> \
 </Query> \
 </query> \
 <viewFields> \
 <ViewFields><FieldRef Name=’Title’ /></ViewFields> \
 </viewFields> \
 <rowLimit>4</rowLimit> \
 </GetListItems> \
 </soapenv:Body> \
 </soapenv:Envelope>”;

$.ajax({
 url: “http://<Server URL>/sites/JDT/_vti_bin/lists.asmx”,
type: “POST”,
dataType: “xml”,
data: soapEnv,
 complete: processListAccessResult,
 contentType: “text/xml; charset=\”utf-8\””
});
 });

// Process result
 function processListAccessResult(xData, status) {

$(xData.responseXML).find(“z\\:row”).each(function () {

var tbl = document.getElementById(‘data’);
 var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
 // if there’s no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
 var iteration = lastRow+1;
 var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

// Title cell
 var cellTitle = row.insertCell(0);
 var NodeTitle = document.createElement(‘a’);
NodeTitle.setAttribute(‘href’,”http://<Server URL>/sites/JDT/Lists/AnonymousList/DispForm.aspx?ID=” + $(this).attr(“ows_ID”));
 NodeTitle.style.textDecoration = “none”;
NodeTitle.innerHTML = “. ” + $(this).attr(“ows_Title”);
cellTitle.appendChild(NodeTitle);

// Date cell
 var cellDate = row.insertCell(1);
 var NodeDate = document.createElement(‘span’);
NodeDate.innerText=$(this).attr(“ows_DateValue”).substring(5,7) + ‘/’ + $(this).attr(“ows_DateValue”).substring(8,10) + ‘/’ + $(this).attr(“ows_DateValue”).substring(0,4);
 cellDate.appendChild(NodeDate);
 cellDate.setAttribute(‘align’,’right’);

});
 }

</script>

<table id=”data” class=”hovertable”>
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th align=”left” width=”70%”>AMK Calendar</th>
 <th align=”right” width=”30%”><a href=”http://<Server URL>/sites/JDT/Lists/AnonymousList/AllItems.aspx”>more-></a></th
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody></tbody>
 </table>

</div>

</body>
 </html>
```

There is also one more method mentioned in below given link

[Read SharePoint List Data and Display it in a HTML Page Using jQuery & SPservices Dynamically](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/313769/read-sharepoint-list-data-and-display-it-in-html-page-using/)

Answer (score 1):

When we are using Page Viewer webpart, it's added a iframe tag into the html. so instead of page viewer you can add your own iframe tag in the html and bind the data in this iframe.